# EF7: dnx ef command error "Value can not be Null"

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I use the command

```
dnx ef
```

the following error occurs:

> C:\Users\Livio\OneDrive\Informatik\Websites\HomeNetwork\src\HomeNetwork.API>dnx ef
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: appEnv
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program..ctor(IServiceProvider > serviceProvider, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv, ILibraryManager libraryManager, > IRuntimeEnvironment runtimeEnv)

I'm using dnvm  1.0.0-beta8 coreclr x86.

My project.json looks like this (in HomeNetwork.API)

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

I created this project without editing the code, expect adding the EF7 Dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using dnvm 1.0.0-beta8 coreclr x86.

Then, you should use the beta8 versions of the dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to fix it by myself for too long. You don't know how thankful I am.